# excel vba (internet explorer) error 424 when for loop exits

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am receiving this error at the end of a `For` loop in Excel VBA when collecting data from a website. All the code before is working perfectly.

Even the following code is giving me the result, but it just gives me an error.

[image: VBA Error 424 ScreenShot]

```
y = 5
total = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children.Length

For i = 0 To total
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("A" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(0).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("B" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(1).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("C" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(2).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("D" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(3).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("E" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(4).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("F" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(5).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("G" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(6).Children(0).innerText
    Worksheets("FS Summary").Range("H" & y).Value = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children(i).Children(7).Children(0).innerText
    y = y + 1
Next i
```

Please advise how can I fix it.

Comment: on which line is the error happening ?

Comment: Notice these repeated chained calls? Try to un-chain them (so you can inspect the runtime values) and extract a function to return the `InnerText` of what you're looking for; [handle runtime errors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling/11021/on-error-statement#t=201611211716388191802) in that function; I'd deem it likely that you're making an assumption about the `Children` that is wrong.

Comment: @iDevlop if I debut and break the code then the error appears right after the loop exists. I get my full result but cant avoid or identify the error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am a beginner. you language is very tough for me to understand. apology. but the link about handling runtime error is some new I am learning. Thanks

Comment: `foo().bar().baz().something().somethingElse()` -> "chained calls". What I meant is that you could do `Set fooResult = foo` and then `Set barResult = fooResult.bar()` and then `Set bazResult = barResult.baz()` and so on.. aka "un-chain" the calls and see exactly which one is failing. But keep reading. You need to figure out *exactly which line is raising the error*. Error handling will help you do that.

Comment: Dear Friends. Thanks for giving me a lovely experience in this site. @Tim Williams gave me the solution and learned new things from Mats Mug.

Answer (score 4):

If (for example) `Children.Length` is 5 then your `i` loop should go from 0 to 4 (ie `total - 1`) since there is no `Children(5)`

Also your code would benefit from some simple refactoring:

```
Dim y, ch, Total, i

y = 5
Set ch = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).Children(0).Children
Total = ch.Length

For i = 0 To Total-1
    With Worksheets("FS Summary")
        .Range("A" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(0).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("B" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(1).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("C" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(2).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("D" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(3).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("E" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(4).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("F" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(5).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("G" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(6).Children(0).innerText
        .Range("H" & y).Value = ch(i).Children(7).Children(0).innerText
    End With
    y = y + 1
Next i
```

Comment: I have changed total - 1 which actually makes sense. But still getting error 424 object required.

Comment: On *which line* ?

Comment: Hi Tim. Actually that total - 1 was the error. since the loop was running one more time and there were no object to return that is why I was getting that error. Thanks Tim. Finally It worked. Thanks.